# discord.js V12 'filter' undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I was updating my bot to discord.js V12 the command ;whois is bringing up an error
(node:553) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Node.js is the current version for Discord.js I do know if it has to do with the code

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { stripIndents } = require("common-tags");
const { getMember, formatDate } = require("../../functions.js");

module.exports = {
  config:{
    name: "whois",
    aliases: ["who", "user", "info"],
   category: "info",
    description: "Returns user information",
    usage: "[username | id | mention]"
  },
    run: (client, message, args) => {
        const member = getMember(message, args.join(" "));

        // Member variables
        const joined = formatDate(member.joinedAt);
        const roles = member.roles
            .filter(r => r.id !== message.guild.id)
            .map(r => r).join(", ") || 'none';
```

If I remove .filter & .map another error pops up with .createdAT

```
  // User variables
        const created = formatDate(member.user.createdAt);

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setFooter(member.displayName, member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic:true }))
            .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic:true }))
            .setColor(member.displayHexColor === '#000000' ? '#ffffff' : member.displayHexColor)
            .setAuthor(`${member.displayName} | WHOIS`, member.user.displayAvatarURL)

            .addField('Member information:', stripIndents`** Display name:** ${member.displayName}
            ** Joined at:** ${joined}
            ** Roles:** ${roles}`, true)

            .addField('User information:', stripIndents`** ID:** ${member.user.id}
            ** Username**: ${member.user.username}
            ** Tag**: ${member.user.tag}
            ** Created at**: ${created}`, true)

            .setTimestamp()

        if (member.user.presence.game) 
            embed.addField('Currently playing', stripIndents`** Name:** ${member.user.presence.activity.name}`);

        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
}
```

Now thats is the whole whois code I don't know what else needs to get updated.

Comment: What's the error associated with `member.user.createAt`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the `GuildMember`'s `roles` collection in v12 you need to use `cache`.

```js
const roles = member.roles.cache.filter(r => r.id !== message.guild.id).map(r => r).join(", ") || 'none';
```

Comment: Okay so it stopped the undefined for filter but now it shows a different error TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined

Comment: Can you please edit into your question the `getMember` function? Also why would you need to `getMember` function? you can use `message.member`

Answer (score 1):

Discord.js Guide:

v12 introduces the concept of managers, you will no longer be able to directly use collection methods such as Collection#get on data structures like Client#users. You will now have to directly ask for cache on a manager before trying to use collection methods. Any method that is called directly on a manager will call the API, such as GuildMemberManager#fetch and MessageManager#delete

- OLD: client.users.get('123456789012345678');

- NEW: client.users.cache.get('123456789012345678');

- OLD: channel.messages.get('123456789012345678');

- NEW: channel.messages.cache.get('123456789012345678');

- OLD: guild.members.get('123456789012345678');

- NEW: guild.members.cache.get('123456789012345678');

Refer to [Updating from v11 to v12](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#before-you-start) for more