# Discord.js Issue with roles

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to create a command that gives a specific role(by name) to a message author. My code right now is

```
client.on('message', message =>{
      if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
      const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
      const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
      const user = message.mentions.users.first();
      if(command === "mod"){
        let role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "test");
        let member = message.mentions.members.first();
        member.roles.add(role)
      }
  });
```

But I'm getting a `TypeError` instead.

```
let role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "test");
                                   ^
TypeError: message.guild.roles.find is not a function
```

Comment: whats is your discord.js version?

Comment: Discord Version V12 uses `.cache` now. So try this: `message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "test")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.js V12 'filter' undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61841794/discord-js-v12-filter-undefined)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 1):

Discord JS v12 introduces the concept of **managers**, you will no longer be able to directly use [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) methods such as [`Collection#get`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get) on data structures like [`Client#users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=users). You will now have to directly ask for a cache on a manager before trying to use collection methods.

---

```js
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "test");
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that in version 12 of discord.js, you need to use `cache`, so your code would be

```js
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === `test`);
let member = message.mentions.members.first();
member.roles.add(role)
```